# How to redirect service stdout to terminal console?

Tags: bash, 20.04, scripts

A service is created and here is the `ExecStart`:

```
  ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/home/admin/bin/besu/bin/besu --config-file=/home/admin/bin/besu_network/node1/config.toml"
```

This command start a service with `sudo systemctl start my.service`. Is there way to redirect the stdout to terminal console? The above script didn't do that and there is nothing on the console.

Comment: Services should generally be headless. The easy answer is to direct output to a file, which you can read at your leisure. A more complex answer is to start a `screen` session, start the service inside that session, and then attach your terminal to that session (that's how many Minecraft servers are run).

Comment: when starting systemd service, I used to redirect to a file and it is not real time.